# .htaccess rewrite not working as intended

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following rewrite rule on my website

```
RewriteRule ^feed/(.+)$ rss/$1 [L]
```

This works fine for URL like this

```
https://example.com/feed/https://anchor.fm/s/db2a6d50/podcast/rss
```

which are redirected to

```
https://example.com/rss/https://anchor.fm/s/db2a6d50/podcast/rss
```

However the following URL

```
https://example.com/feed/https:/feeds.buzzsprout.com/1560791.rss
```

is redirected to

```
https://example.com/rss/.buzzsprout.com/1560791.rss
```

How can I update my rewrite rule to get the full part of the URL that is right after the FIRST `feed/` entry?

Comment: Will your inline URL request always begin with https?

Comment: There must be something else going on here... how are these URLs ultimately handled/routed? What other directives do you have? How are you "seeing" the resulting URL? Since this is an internal rewrite, not a "redirect". The rule you've posted won't rewrite the URL that you say "works fine" in the first example since the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ has already had multiple contiguous slashes reduced, so the double slash is not preserved. And it wouldn't just remove an arbitrary string like `https:/feeds` in the second URL.

Comment: Not necessarily. I need to get anything in the original url that is after the 1st 'feed/'. Sometimes the https can be missing

Comment: Mr White yes this is what's happening. I'm having logs tracing the opened urls and I can see that this doesn't work as intended when there's 'feed/' within the url as explained in the 2nd case